# Elastic beanstalk is not pushing updated version of source code on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci

we have a situation where incremental source code deployment is not working in Elastic beasntalk.

so If a new elastic beanstalk environment is created with source code package, it works and EC2 instance gets the source package, but next time if I want to deploy a new version of source code, gitlab pipeline is successful and package reaches to the elastic beanstalk as I can see it under application version, however new source code does not deploy on existing EC2 instances.

we are using deployment_policy and rolling update type as "Immutable" in elastic beanstalk configuration. one thing, that's observed is, if we terminate existing Ec2 instance, ASG spin up a new EC2 instance and that contains updated source code.

also, manual code deployment from Elastic beanstalk console is working and revised code version gets updated on EC2.

we are using Terraform to build up the EB infrastructure and gitlab for package deployment as pipeline.

ASG is set as min_size = 1, max_size = 2

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure a deploy token on gitlab? Did you follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/devops/deploy-a-docker-application-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-gitlab/) instructions for more details about how to deploy with gitlab CD pipes?
I think it is an environment variables problem! Hope it helps.

Comment: The source code is hosted on Jfrog artifactory and is getting picked up by the pipeline so I think here I won't be needing the gitlab deploy token.